# Angular 2 : How to filter records between two dates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

```
{
 "id":1,
 "name":"Jack",
 "date":"01-06-2017"
},
{
 "id":2,
 "name":"Allen",
 "date":"07-08-2017"
},
{
 "id":3,
 "name":"Annie",
 "date":"22-11-2017"
},
```

This JSON stored in 'members' Array I want filter the member based on start and end date like:

```
 let startDate;
 let endDate;
 let selectedMembers = this.members.filter(m => m.date > startDate && m.date < endDate);
```

something like that..

Comment: Did you went through the basics of `ts` or `js` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution of my problem:

```
members:any[] = [{
 "id":1,
 "name":"Jack",
 "date":"01-06-2017"
},
{
 "id":2,
 "name":"Allen",
 "date":"07-08-2017"
},
{
 "id":3,
 "name":"Annie",
 "date":"22-11-2017"
}];

let start = "01-02-2017";
let end = "06-07-2017";

let.selectedMembers = this.members.filter(
m => new Date(m.date) >= new Date(startDate) && new Date(m.date) <= new Date(endDate)
);

console.log(selectedMembers);
```

Answer (score 1):

u need first to transform the dates from string to Date type in order to compare them properly then do something like:

```
let members: any[] = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jack",
        "date": "01-06-2017" // this should be of object Date()
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Allen",
        "date": "07-08-2017" // this should be of object Date()
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Annie",
        "date": "22-11-2017" // this should be of object Date()
        }];

    let start = "01-02-2017;  // this should be of object Date()
    let end = "06-07-2017"; // this should be of object Date()

        let selectedMembers = members.filter(m => {
          if ( m.date > start && m.date < end) // or you can cast here to Date()
            return m;
    });

    console.log(selectedMembers);
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort dates stored as strings, you should use an ISO based format:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

The line you wrote will work with dates like that:

```
{  "id":1,  "name":"Jack",  "date":"2017-06-01" }, 
{  "id":2,  "name":"Allen",  "date":"2017-08-07" }, 
{  "id":3,  "name":"Annie",  "date":"2017-11-22" }
```

If not, you have to parse the strings to date object and use them in the comparison. Something like this:

```
let startDate = new Date('2017-05-01');
 let endDate = new Date('2017-09-01);
 let selectedMembers = this.members.filter(m => new Date(m.date) > startDate && new Date(m.date) < endDate);
```

Comment: glad to hear that. Don't forget to vote up the answer so other people can know that it would help them

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse your date format, then convert it to **TIMESTAMP** for comparison.

```js
members = [{
 "id":1,
 "name":"Jack",
 "date":"01-06-2017"
},
{
 "id":2,
 "name":"Allen",
 "date":"07-08-2017"
},
{
 "id":3,
 "name":"Annie",
 "date":"22-11-2017"
}];

const startDate ="25-06-2017";
const  endDate = "10-11-2017";

// Here reverse the date format & then convert to TIMESTAMP
function reverseAndTimeStamp(dateString) {
const reverse = new Date(dateString.split("-").reverse().join("-"));
return reverse.getTime();
}
 // A simple array filter like what you did
 const  selectedMembers = members.filter(m => { 
 return reverseAndTimeStamp(m.date) > reverseAndTimeStamp(startDate) && reverseAndTimeStamp(m.date) < reverseAndTimeStamp(endDate)
 }
 );
 
  console.log(selectedMembers); // the result objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use french date format, you need own made transformer between string and Date object.

Then you have to deal with Date javascript object and timestamp representation.

Something like this will work.

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  // note parts[1]-1
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]).getTime();
}

let startDate = parseDate('01-06-2017');
let endDate = parseDate('01-06-2018');

let selectedMembers = this.members.filter(m => {
    const current = parseDate(m.date);
    return current > startDate && current < endDate;
});
```